# $scope-less Controller retrieving data from webapi doesn't update binding in AngularJS 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-scope

ok, reading the link below, in Angular 1.3 they're recommending not using '$scope.x' inside the controller and instead using 'this.x'

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

What seems to break is calling to $http to get data (inherently async) but the binding doesn't get updated when a 2.4 second webapi call happens.

I can see that the webapi call is made and returns data but the data doesn't get updated to the page.

Every example I look at is using the $scope usage pattern. I'm trying to future proof my code as I have time.

here's the JSON that gets returned from the service

> [{"Venue":"Index","Symbol":"ADDA.IDX","SecurityId":3320,"Type":"Index","Description":"AMEX
>   Advance Decline Difference"},
>
> {"Venue":"Index","Symbol":"ADDD.IDX","SecurityId":3321,"Type":"Index","Description":"OTC
>   Advance Decline Difference"},
>   ...

Here's the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<body>
    <h1>My Test</h1>
    <div id="t" ng-controller="SecuritiesController as venue">
        <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="s in venue.securities">
                 {{s.SecurityId}} {{s.Symbol}} {{s.Description}}
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/angular-1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/securityController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here's the controller

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SecuritiesController', function ($http) {
    $http.get("/api/securities").success(function(results)
        { this.securities = results.data; }
    );
});
```

Comment: yes, in the markup i'm using the 'controller as alias' syntax and the instance of the controller is called venue.

look through the syntax indicated in the included link and you'll see something similar

Comment: that's xml not json. Never even tried using xml in angular but I doubt it will parse it to javascript array/object without some additional code

Comment: yeah, sorry. I copied out of chrome hitting the service and it converts it to xml for visualization. I'll get the json from the debugger tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SecuritiesController', function ($http) {
    var controller = this;

    $http.get("/api/securities").success(function(results)
        { controller.securities = results.data; }
    );
});
```

Inside the response function, this actually refers to the Closure block instead of your controller.

Question Author: remove the .data and it works - my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final fixed code.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SecuritiesController', function ($http) {
    var controller = this;

    $http.get("/api/securities").success(function (results)
    { controller.securities = results; }
    );
});
```

Note: it appears that Angular/javascript doesn't support 'this' in the closure thus the need to explicitly define a capture variable